# Multiple query updates on an array of elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have an array which is not necessarily sorted. I have to perform Q queries on it. 
The queries are like this:
Given the array and an index I. I have to update all the elements that come in that array from index i+1 to n such that A[I]>A[j].
The queries are dependent on each other ie the changes made to query 1 will reflect in query 2.

The changes to made for every query are like this:

```
for j=I+1 to N:
    if A[j]<A[I]:
      A[j]=0
```

I have no idea how to approach the problem. I am thinking of something along the lines of a binary indexed tree. But I am not sure. In the hint, it says to use advanced sorting algorithms.

Comment: can you add more details, like what is 'j' and value to update to?

Comment: @Kaushal Added a code snippet to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here`s O((q+n) log n) approach:

1. Build a segment tree for range minimum query for given array
2. Also create an array marked[] to keep track of nodes which should be made zero
3. Now for each query: if given index I is marked, do nothing (you did not give constraints for elements so i`m assuming all A[i] >=0)
4. if it's not marked we can find some index j in interval [I+1, n] such that A[j] is minimum value in this interval
5. if such A[j] is >= A[i] we are donw with the query
6. otherwise:

   - mark index j, (marked[j] = true)
   - update segment tree setting position j to some large value (infinity)
   - continue steps from step 4 till we are done with the query

It might seem this is slow because for each query we can potentially make n updates in segment tree, yet we can notice that each element will be marked at most once so worst case is O((q+n) log n)